# Get left part of the string until the last number in the string

Tags: javascript

There is a string that definitely contains a number.

Example: **"jhgkjhgnk39dfsjhg437sdfgsd"**.

How to extract the left part of this string before the last number?

The answer for the string above:

**"jhgkjhgnk39dfsjhg"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could phrase this using a regex replacement:

```js
var input = "jhgkjhgnk39dfsjhg437sdfgsd";
var first = input.replace(/\d+\D*$/, "");
console.log(input + "\n" + first);
```

The strategy here is to remove the final digits followed by optional all non digit characters, leaving behind the substring you want.